# Prove that commuting matrices over an algebraically closed field are simultaneously triangularizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, triangularization

Given an algebraically closed field $\mathbb K$ and matrices $A, B \in \mathbb K^{n \times n}$ such that $A B = B A$, show that $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously triangularizable, i.e., show that there exists a matrix $T$ such that $T^{-1} A T$ and $T^{-1} B T$ are both upper triangular.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: The hint is to show that A and B have a the same eigenvector but i dont know how to approach this problem

Comment: Is it given that $\mathbb K$ is algebraically closed? Otherwise, I am not sure that the hint is true.

Comment: Not mentioned but i would take that as a given yes

Comment: I think we mean the same thing sorry for my bad english i am from germany. It means that it is similar to a upper triangular matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that any eigenspace of $A$ is $B$-invariant. Explicitly, given any vector $v$ such that $Av = \lambda v,$ we have that $A(Bv) = (AB)v = (BA)v = B(Av) = B(\lambda v) = \lambda Bv$ so that $Bv$ is either $0$ or an eigenvector of $A$ with respect to $\lambda.$ Given any nonzero eigenspace $W_\lambda$ of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A,$ we conclude that $B$ restricts to a linear operator $B|_{W_\lambda} : W_\lambda \to W_\lambda.$ Considering that $\mathbb K$ is algebraically closed, the characteristic polynomial of $B|_{W_\lambda}$ splits into (not necessarily distinct) linear factors, hence there exists a linear polynomial $x - \mu$ such that $B|_{W_\lambda} - \mu I$ is the zero operator on $W_\lambda.$ Consequently, there exists a nonzero vector $w$ in $W_\lambda$ such that $Bw = \mu w$ and $Aw = \lambda w.$ We conclude therefore that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors.

Can you finish the proof now that you have proven the hint?

Comment: Now i need to show that the T matrix exists but again i´m missing an approach for that

Comment: I need to show that T exists at all. i sat too long on this problem i probably dont see the obvious right now

Comment: Of course, there exists a $T$ for $A$ and a $T'$ for $B$ because $\mathbb K$ is algebraically closed. I am wondering if you have proven this fact. If so, then the same $T$ will work for both $A$ and $B$ because $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvectors, as I have proven in my solution.

Comment: Okay i think i got it i just have to fully understand your proof

Comment: Out of interest how would i prove if it is algebraically closed?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [Theorem 2.9](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/invariant_subspaces.pdf) of these notes by Pete L. Clark.

Comment: Okay thank you!

Comment: I still struggle to see why a matrix T exists if A and B are simultaneously triangularizable

Comment: We form the matrix $T$ by taking a basis of eigenvectors for $A.$ But the eigenvectors of $A$ are precisely the eigenvectors of $B,$ hence the matrix $T$ is a basis of eigenvectors for $B.$

Comment: yes i got that but why do they need to be simultaneously triangularizable